# Is there such a thing as an embedded batch language?

Tags: configuration-files, scripting-language, embedded-language, polish-notation

I was recently looking through a configuration file for a game I was playing, when it struck me how much the language used in the configuration file resembled a [batch language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Command_line_interface_languages) with each line formulated as a command, how simple the syntax was and how immediately clear it was what every line in the file was doing without requiring any surrounding lines of context. Still, I know of no batch language that is frequently used as an [extension language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language#Extension.2Fembeddable_languages), to be embedded into another application.

Are there in fact no batch languages that are designed to be embedded into other programs (foremost, I would imagine, for configuration files), or is it just that I haven't heard about them? If there are, what such languages are there?

And if there are not, is it possible to in some way run a shell script or similar from a program in an isolated environment with custom-defined commands, and access the resulting environment variables from the program afterwards?

**Edit:** By batch language, I mean that it should be possible to give commands, i.e. formulate lines on the form `<command> [<arg1> [<arg2> [...] ] ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical examples of this are probably [Lua](http://www.lua.org) and [Tcl](https://www.tcl.tk), both of which were designed to be embedded into other programs.

Lua is more commonly used these days.

There is a list of [Lua scriptable software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lua-scriptable_software) on Wikipedia, and another list maintained on the [Lua wiki](https://sites.google.com/site/marbux/home/where-lua-is-used).

Comment: Hm, Tcl looks interesting, and all operations are commands! +1 for that! :)

Comment: On the other hand, it would also bee good if you could define variables using a more compact notation, like `var = value`, or `var: value`. Do you know if there is any interpreted language that supports operations that are commands, _and_ this type of notation? And that is cross-platform and not coupled to the operating system, i.e. suitable to be used to make configuration scripts (or similar) for applications?